# Report Header in MS Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, report

How can I add a report header in MS Report.
I added Page headers and footers in it from menu Report>> Page Header
but can't see anything for REport header.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score -2):

HY! From the rdlc file you can insert the header and the footer! Just go on the body and with a right click you can choose Insert>>page header.

Comment: The original question was about adding a "REPORT header" (not a "page header"). A report header is something that would appear at the top of page 1 only.